# How to get pictures of the Wordpress post

Tags: post-meta, gallery

During the post creation of a post in Wordpress, I add 2 pictures in the post Gallery. How can I retrieve uploaded pictures URLs to display them on the other template?

Comment: Something similar to this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114341/21376

Answer (score 0):

When you upload an attachment from the post edit screen, WordPress set the current post ID as the `post_parent` of the attachment. And that's how you get these attachments:

```
$post_ID = 123;
$attachments = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'post_parent'    => $post_ID,
        'post_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image/*'
    )
);
foreach ( $attachments as $a ) {
    $info = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $a->ID, 'full' );
    $info[ 0 ]; // url to the image
    $info[ 1 ]; // image with in px
    $info[ 2 ]; // image height in px
    $info[ 3 ]; // TRUE if the image is a resized one
    dump( $info[ 0 ] );
}
```

Codex for [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)