# Only current gallery images with get_attached_media

Tags: media, gallery, images

On my page the gallery images are cycled and I would like to show their title as a caption. Since `get_post_gallery_images` only retrieves the thumbnail-url of the gallery images I have tried to use `get_attached_media('image', $post);` instead.

The following code gives me the url and the title of the gallery images:

foreach($images as $image) {
 $titleArr[] = $image->post_title;
 $urlArr[] = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
}

However, `get_attached_media('image', $post);` returns all images that have ever been attached to this post, even if they are no longer used in the post. Also, for posts where the gallery images are attached to another post, they do not appear.

Is there an equivalent of `get_attached_media('image', $post);` that returns all the image urls and titles of the images **currently** in the gallery. Preferably in gallery order.

Comment: It's better to edit your post than add a comment with code in :)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer using Shortcode which helped: [How to get Page/Post Gallery attachment images in order they are set in backend using WP_Query()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80408/how-to-get-page-post-gallery-attachment-images-in-order-they-are-set-in-backend)

My working code now looks like this:

```
// Extract the shortcode arguments from the $page or $post
$shortcode_args = shortcode_parse_atts(get_match('/\[gallery\s(.*)\]/isU', $post->post_content));

// get the ids specified in the shortcode call
$ids = $shortcode_args["ids"];

$attachments = get_posts(
    array(
        'include' => $ids, 
        'post_status' => 'inherit', 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'order' => 'menu_order ID', 
        'orderby' => 'post__in', //required to order results based on order specified the "include" param
    )
);

if ($attachments) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    $urlArr[] = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
    $titleArr[] = $attachment->post_title;
        }
    }
```